# Android: Battery usage of each application

Tags: android, sdk, power-management

Is there anyway to get the battery usage info per application per second in API, adb shell, ...?

Comment: Any news on this questions?

Comment: I also suffer from this problem if you find any solution please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than the battery usage screen in Settings, there is no API or command-line way to get this information.

Comment: I want to get the info that the battery usage screen gets. Is it possible to get it using sdk or ndk? Because that is not part of the public API.

Comment: @phoenix7: You can get it via custom firmware -- that is it.

Comment: For anyone coming here from the future, this post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27821415/275524

Comment: This answer is not correct, there is a possibility to access that data, GSam Battery Monitor does that and without any root access either.

Answer (score 2):

just try to read http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/1.6_r2/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java/ , then you can get the info shown in the battery usage screen. the key class are IBatteryStats and BatteryStatsImpl.

Comment: Can you please provide a detailed answer, I am trying for more than a month, but no luck.