# how to get the percentage of battery consumed by my app in last 24 hour

Tags: android, battery

I have go through following links to get the amount battery consumed by my app but i am not getting the solution for this query 
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149121/android-battery-usage-of-each-application)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867241/how-to-get-percentage-of-battery-usage-by-each-app-in-android-programatically)
i have even try  with this android class but no solution found with this, even search for the lib but no lib found for the battery .please suggest the the solution for this .. as other various app are having this functionality (battery doctor ,du battery saver , battery saver)

Comment: summary: the battery usage api is private, also in order to get percentage for your app consumption you will have to calculate other apps usage to find your's, check this, it's really old post, but it could help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770021/how-to-get-information-about-android-battery-usage-by-application

Comment: i have tired with this adb shell dumpsys batterystats  but how to decode this text file in the android app