# Battery usage by running application in android os

Tags: android, cpu-usage, battery, battery-saver

How to get battery usage by running application.its start with when my mobile battery is full to till.my application required list with each battery usage in percentage.
 I already try this 
Cpu_usages = 100*((totaltime)/Herz)/seconds;

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, and I don't understand your sentences. Are you talking about [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) ?

Comment: Sorry my English is not too good.I am not talking about this link.I want to know Each application in android run independent process ,each process conssumed some battery %.want to get % and list with application name.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149121/android-battery-usage-of-each-application)

Comment: Hey @UDKOX. I did got solution using this : [link](https://github.com/jackvt93/Open-Battery-Saver)